# How to increase a Tcl Tk scale by 0.1

Tags: tcl, scale, tk-toolkit

How can I increase scale widget in Tcl/Tk to increase by a floating point number e.g 0.1?. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

package require Tk

scale .meter -from 0 -to 10  -variable r -label meter -orient horizontal
pack .meter  -fill both -expand true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`-resolution`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/scale.htm) option:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

package require Tk

scale .meter -from 0 -to 10  -variable r -label meter -orient horizontal -resolution 0.1
pack .meter  -fill both -expand true
```

Will take all increment/decrement by 0.1.